# Directtostage error when playing published application in another computer

Tags: video, lingo, adobe-director

I have a Director application that has several modules, but one in particular decided to not work. That is the Video section of the program.

So basically when Im developing in Director, everything works perfectly, but when I try to run the application in another computer, I get the error "Property doesen't exists: directtostage", and comes from this like of code:

```
sprite("VideoShape").member.DirectToStage = true;
```

The direct to stage property allows the video to have a better (and faster) rendering, thus allowing it to actually be playable. Without it, although works, makes is ultra slow and flikery, so having it is considered to be important.

I have checked and there is a video played at the time that line of code kicks in ,so i'm sure it "has" that property. Please keep in mind that the video plays perfectly when I am testing it out in director, when I publish it it still works fine, and only when I tried it on another computer has the error occurred.

The videos are in mp4 format (Quicktime) and the destination computer is running on Windows Vista.

Did any of you had this problem and knows of a possible fix?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out that the pc in question did not have Quicktime installed. It was fixed afterwards. thanks for anyone that looked at the question :P